# Calculate expression and paste after cursor

Tags: expression-register

I want a shortcut for evaluating a yanked expression and pasting the result after the cursor.

Suppose I've written `i1+1<ESC>0y$$`, now I'd like to paste the result of that, `2`, after the cursor. Is that possible?

I can take that expression and replace it using bc, e.g. `i1+1<ESC>!!bc<CR>`, but that's not what I want (although it's quite neat).

I can evaluate expressions and insert them into the text using `i<C-R>=1+1<CR>`. I have `set clipboard=unnamedplus` so I could take my yanked expression and paste it with ctrl+shift+v into the `i<C-R>=` prompt, and then I pretty much have what I want.

Now then, how do I create a shortcut of that, i.e. of (pseudo) `i<C-R>=<C-Shift-V><CR>`?

If you know any other way of doing this sort of thing then that's fine too, thanks.

Comment: That works, thanks! I guess I'll see which register will make most sense to use, but anyway, using ````<C-R>.```` or other register inside the expression prompt was the key. ````noremap == i<C-R>=<C-R>+<ESC>```` was pretty much what I needed (I'll tweak it as I go along). Make an answer out of your suggestion and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<C-R>`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html?#c_CTRL-R) from the prompt of the `=` expression to insert the contents of a register. For example, `<C-R>"` for the contents of the default register, which is where your yanked expression is stored.

This would work to insert the result of the expression in the default register:

```
i<C-R>=<C-R>"<CR><Esc>
```

You can also use `<C-R>.` for your last insertion (so you don't even need to yank an expression.) After `i1+1<Esc>`, you can use `i<C-R>=<C-R>.<CR><Esc>` to insert the result of the inserted expression at the current location.

Comment: `”=<C-R>”<CR>p` is a tiny bit shorter/more direct than entering insert mode.

Comment: Nice use of the dot register!

Comment: @Rich Those right double quotation marks probably won't work well as a vim command if someone tries to copy/paste that sequence.

Comment: @BLayer Ah the perils of browsing vi.se on my phone. Well spotted!