# Insert result of expression after cursor

Tags: normal-mode, functions, expression-register

This function inserts the current date and time on the line after the cursor:

```
function! InsertDate()
    put = strftime('%FT%T%z')
endfunction
```

I'd like to insert the date and time on the current line after the cursor instead.

I thought it would be as simple as:

```
function! InsertDate()
    normal "=strftime('%FT%T%z')<CR>p
endfunction
```

But that doesn't insert anything. I don't understand why.

I also thought this should work:

```
function! InsertDate()
    normal a<C-R>=strftime('%FT%T%z')
endfunction
```

But that inserts `<C-R>=strftime('%FT%T%z')` literally.

I thought maybe I needed to add `<CR>` or `<CR><Esc>` to the end but it made no difference.

What am I missing?

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22891/calculate-expression-and-paste-after-cursor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```
function! InsertDate()
    execute "normal! \"=strftime('%FT%T%z')\<CR>p"
endfunction
```

Your tentative were good but the normal argument do not interpret the `<CR>` code. In the solution I propose I use the `\<CR>` expansion within `"` strings.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I eventually came up with `execute "normal i\<C-R>=strftime('%FT%T%z')\<CR>"`, which is more verbose but does the same.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: I would do it differently. Make `InsertDate()` return just the date, and if you need to insert it, just use `:put =InsertDate()` or from insert mode: `i<c-r>=InsertDate()<cr>`  which I think is easier to use

Comment: @Christian, I have tested it but to me the put command always create a new line.

Comment: yes of course, put is linewise. What I was trying to say is, you could use the `InsertDate()` function in any way you like, add it in insert mode after the cursor, or just *put* it into a line below or just *echo* the current date at the command line. The function is flexible enough and is not bound to be only used in one single way.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt at that point the `InsertDate()` seems rather pointless, yeah? The idea is to make it easy.

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge au contraire. I don't want a function `InsertDateBelowCursor()`, `InsertDateAfterCursor()`, `EchoInsertDate()` . I just want to re-use the exiting function, that is easier to remember, instead of all those silly `strftime()` flags

Comment: Prefer `normal!`

Comment: I continue to forget :-)